# How to check and assign values in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. I want to retrieve the value from my checkboxes in PHP and read it.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" NAME="andras">Male
<input type="radio" NAME="andras">Female
```

**PHP**

```
$number= array($_POST['andras']);
$fylo=$number[$i];
```

Comment: Your buttons don't have any values.

Comment: ...not to mention an unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `value` attribute to give values to the buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="andras" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="andras" value="female">Female
```

Then in the PHP, `$_POST['andras']` will contain either `male` or `female`.